# Video Streaming through RTMP

Tags: rtmp, red5, video-streaming

I need to convert as RTSP live monitering URL rtsp://mylocation.4545 to RTMP url rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/livestream1
Iam using following command through ffmpeg in centos

```
 ffmpeg -i "rtsp://127.0.0.1.4545/live" -f flv -r 25 -s 640x480 -an "rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/livestream1"
```

But When Iam trying this Iam getting the following error..

```
 [h264 @ 0x24de1e0]number of reference frames exceeds max (probably corrupt input), discarding one
Last message repeated 1 times
 [h264 @ 0x24de1e0]concealing 845 DC, 845 AC, 845 MV errors
 [h264 @ 0x24de1e0]number of reference frames exceeds max (probably corrupt input), discarding one
Last message repeated 243 times  83kB time=0.08 bitrate=8477.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=2067    
[h264 @ 0x24de1e0]cbp too large (4294967295) at 31 16
[h264 @ 0x24de1e0]error while decoding MB 31 16
[h264 @ 0x24de1e0]concealing 898 DC, 898 AC, 898 MV errors
[h264 @ 0x24de1e0]number of reference frames exceeds max (probably corrupt input), di scarding one
 [h264 @ 0x24de1e0]concealing 1584 DC, 1584 AC, 1584 MV errors477.4kbits/s dup=0 drop =3942    
 [h264 @ 0x24de1e0]number of reference frames exceeds max (probably corrupt input), discarding one
 [root@server www]#  q=2.0 size=      83kB time=0.08 bitrate=8477.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=5087
```

If anybody can help me please..?